# Postgres COPY invalid syntax for integer

Tags: postgresql

My table,

```
       Table "public.product_status"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers
--------+-----------------------+-----------
 id     | integer               | not null
 code   | character varying(10) |
 notes  | text                  |
```

First line of my CSV file,

```
1,S,blah blah blah
```

Copy command,

```
=# copy product_status from 'status_table.csv' with csv;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1"
CONTEXT:  COPY product_status, line 1, column id: "1"
```

Really don't understand how that's invalid syntax for an integer!
Even postgres seems to agree with me,

```
=# insert into product_status values (1,'S','blah blah blah');
=# copy product_status to STDOUT with csv;
1,S,blah blah blah
```

Any ideas? Other questions I found on the site didn't seem applicable to whatever I've done wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably an “invisible” character at the beginning of the file.

Examine the contents; if you are on sume UNIX, you could use `od -c status_table.csv`.

Chances are that there is a useless [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file. Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz, I did have BOM in my file!

Comment: Thank you - `od -c ` is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, and my answer was the same as above, a "useless [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file."  Here is how I removed it.

1) Open the file in vim

```
vim file_with_bom.txt
```

2) Set the 'nobomb' option

```
:set nobomb
```

3) Save the file and exit

```
:wq
```

Hope this helps!